# Restricting access to azure key vault to only the vault owner

Tags: azure, key, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to create an azure key vault that is only accessible to the vault creator and to whom he wishes to give access to, be it a person or an app, and is not accessible to the azure subscription administrators or users that are hierarchically superior inside the subscription to the vault owner?

In such a case, anyone but the vault creator would have access and management over the key vault, and subscription administrators could at best only delete the vault.

Comment: Hi @rsp, unfortunately azure key vault only supports RBAC (Role based access control) or key vault based access policies. 

Keyvault access policy can be set by anybody who have controbutor access to key vault either direct or inherited from resource group or subscription.

If you have set Azure role based access control, only people who are owner or user access administrator of Keyvault either direct or inherited from resource group, subscription or management group, can add/update.